# How can we encourage people to link to content here?

Tags: discussion, 7-essential-metas, site-promotion

If you track our [stats on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/), you'll see that our percent answered and answer ratio are both, B"H, in good shape, and our questions per day is in a decent place and rising steadily. However, our user count and visits per day have been more or less flat, following a big jump when this site opened on SE 2.0. What this tells me is that we're doing a great job of generating great content and answering people's questions, but we have work to do in growing the community and making more outside people aware of the great content here.

One way to make more people aware of our content is to get people to link to content here in their blogs, Twitter feeds, Facebook feeds, etc., especially if they are influential people. How can we get prominent writers, bloggers, Twitterers, etc. to link to judaism.SE content?

Update: Take a look at [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/) for inspiration.

Comment: It would be a good idea to try to get bloggers to link to the site (and maybe offer to link back).

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer: This may be a non-answer.**

I have a feeling that high-quality and high-accessibility content is the best tool we can use to that end, and that if we refine and keep up the high standards we have been, they will *eventually* do more to attract people to the site than strategic link placement. It happens to be that Judaism.SE has remarkably good placement on Google search results pages ([a recent example](http://www.google.com/#q=davar%20shebakedusha&nfpr=1&ei=aOjbTe3HMMTl0QHY1b34Dw&sqi=2&start=0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=6af0f014ae16db6c)). [Assuming people are asking questions that have been asked before] this could be very (passive yet) effective in gathering people from the social media and other realms of the HTTP universe.

Comment: I agree that quality should be our top priority and that high-quality content will eventually bring in readers and linkers. However, I think that we should consider additional ways of directly addressing the latter.

Comment: Exactly. Build it and they will come.

Comment: @yydl In the long run, this is true. However, had I taken this attitude strictly on mi.yodeya and not taken certain steps to promote the site (such as an ad on http://torahmusings.com), the community would have taken much, much longer to grow and may never have attained critical mass.

Comment: @IssacMoses Well, yes. If you want more immediate growth then that advertising would work. But the best growth (and most lasting) is organic. Slow and over time. Word of mouth helps too (that's what got me here).

Answer (score 2):

A. start by posting links yourself. Facebook, twitter, linkedin, whereever you have any visibility, post links to good questions. Emphasis on the *good* - interesting, surprising, helpful, etc. - questions and answers. Same goes on any other relevant forum.
I've seen big upticks on other sites after a popular question gets some visibility via social sites... And you only need one or two to post, it often gets retwitted and etc.

B. Provide answers to specific questions - e.g. [Jeff's blog post on helping experts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/helping-the-experts-get-answers/).

C. There are some specific badges to support external linking...