# Please post links to J.SE content on other sites!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This is not a question; this is a request:

**Please post links to content from this site on other sites!**

If you look at our statistics on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/jewish-life-and-learning-migration-of-mi-yodeya-com), it seems clear that we're doing a great job of getting people's questions answered (as always), but what we need to bump up are the number of people reading the site, and the number of people taking the next step and posting questions.

As suggested by AviD [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/how-can-we-encourage-people-to-link-to-content-here/157#157), one way to bring readers in is by posting links to our content on social media sites and the like. There are some handy links on the front page under "Help us grow this site!" to facilitate linking to the whole site, and on each question's page on the upper-left to facilitate linking to that question. Please go do this. Any time you see something particularly interesting, think "would my online 'friends' find this interesting too?"

[Here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/what-are-your-favorite-online-forums-in-which-jewish-links-are-posted)'s a place where you can suggest more fora in which to promote this site.

[Here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224/what-blogs-have-linked-to-this-site)'s a list of blogs that have pointed here. If you post to a blog or see that someone else does, please update it!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to keep interest in the site is with new questions and answers. The lack of new material will with time cause an erosion of interest.

Comment: Absolutely. Lots of high-quality material is the main thing we want. Increasing the number of people who frequent this site is one way to help that happen. There are only so many high-quality questions per day in the heads of our current crop of active community members. To break through that limitation, we need more people. But yes, maybe we should also have a meta-plea to post more high-quality questions, though I  think that should go without [additional](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) saying for people who read meta.